# im including php file but after that my css and bootstrap is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, web-deployment

im including `db.php` on the top of index.php file..but after including it my css and bootstrap is not working

1. this is my php file which im including. `includes` inside include is a folder and db.php file is inside it

   ```
   <?php 
   include("includes/db.php");
   ?>
   ```

2.this is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>E-COMMERCE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="top">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-6 offer">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">welcome guest</a>
         <a href="#">shopping card total price:inr 100,total item 2 </a>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
         <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="registration.php">register</a></li>
            <li><a href="customer/my_account.php">my account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">go to cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3.this is the php code for dynamic slider

```
<?php
$get_table="select * from slider LIMIT 0,1";
$run_slider=mysqli_query($con,$get_table);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_slider)){
    $slider_name=$row['slider_name'];
    $slider_image=$row['slider-image'];
    echo "<div class='item active'>
        <img src='admin_area/slider/$slider_image' alt='$slider_name'>
        </div>";
}
?>

<?php
$get_table="select * from slider LIMIT 1,3";
$run_slider=mysqli_query($con,$get_table);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_slider)) {
    $slider_name=$row['slider_name'];
    $slider_image=$row['slider-image'];
    echo "<div class='item'>
        <img src='admin_area/slider/$slider_image' alt='$slider_name' >
        </div>";
}

?>
```